# iOS: in-app browser sharing cookies with main browser (prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession=false). How to hide Apple popup?

Tags: ios, swift, session-cookies

If I set `authenticationSession.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true` in my `ASWebAuthenticationSession`, the in-app browser won't share cookies with the iOS browser.

This is unfortunately not what I want, because I'm using OpenID to share credentials among other apps, and therefore I've set it to false.

However now everytime I open the browser from the app I get the Apple popup:

```
"Your app" Wants to Use "your website" to Sign In
This allows the app and website to share information about you.
```

Is there a way to disable this popup? (and still share cookies with iOS browser)

Comment: No. The pop up is there for a reason. If Apple didn't want the pop up then they wouldn't show it.

Comment: It's so UXwise ugly

Comment: It is a privacy protection. The user needs to know that their information is being shared across apps.

Comment: It opens that popup both when logging in, and logging out. It would have been nice to be able to dismiss it after informing the user the first time.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't provide a logout function in this kind of situation, since you are using shared credentials calling the logout will potentially impact other applications. You can simply throw away the token when logging out. Alternatively, use an ephemeral session for logging out, passing your apps token